# Speed of sklearn.utils._fast_dict.pyx

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cython, cythonize

I am trying to build and use `sklearn.utils._fast_dict` myself but got a speed problem.
First I copied the two files: `_fast_dict.pyx` and `_fast_dict.pxd` and rename them as `sklearn_fast_dict.pyx` and `sklearn_fast_dict.pxd`.
Then I run `setup.py` to build `sklearn_fast_dict.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`

```py
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
    'sklearn_fast_dict',
    sources=['sklearn_fast_dict.pyx'],
    language='c++',
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    library_dirs=[],
    libraries=[],
    extra_compile_args=[],
    extra_link_args=[]
)))
```

And here are my test codes:

```py
from sklearn_fast_dict import IntFloatDict
keys = np.arange(0, 100000, dtype=np.intp)
values = np.arange(100000, 200000, dtype=np.float64)
# ordinary python dict
ndic = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
dic = IntFloatDict(keys, values)

def iter1():
    r1 = []
    r2 = []

    for i in range(100):
        t1 = datetime.now()
        for item in dic:
            pass
        t2 = datetime.now()
        for item in ndic.items():
            pass
        t3 = datetime.now()
        r1.append(t2-t1)
        r2.append(t3-t2)

    print(min(r1), max(r1), np.mean(r1))
    # 0:00:00.005984 0:00:00.009001 0:00:00.007115
    print(min(r2), max(r2), np.mean(r2))
    # 0:00:00.000982 0:00:00.002024 0:00:00.001707
```

Which shows that the python `dict` is faster than the `IntFloatDict`
Is there anywhere I did wrong in the building and usage?
Thanks!

UPDATE:
I tried to add a function `get_values` into a similar class Int32Dict(the only difference between the Int32Dict and IntFloatDict is the datatype of keys and values). The function:

```py
def get_values(self, np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=1] keys):
    cdef int size = keys.size
    cdef np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=1] values = np.empty(size, dtype=np.int32)
    cdef int index
    for index in range(size):
        values[index] = self[keys[index]]
    return values
```

And normal get_values operation on normal python dict:

```py
def n_get_values(dic: dict, keys: np.ndarray):
    size = keys.size
    ret = np.empty(size, dtype=np.int32)
    for index in range(size):
        ret[index] = dic[keys[index]]
    return ret
```

The get_values function is about three times faster compared with with normal get_values function.

Comment: As shown above, `r2` is the result of normal python `dict` and is 3 times faster than the `IntFloatDict` on average

Comment: It looks like the code in `sklearn` does the iteration through the underlying C++ type rather than through the Python wrapper (as you're doing). I get the feeling this is designed to be fast to use from Cython but the Python interface is just a convenience so is slow(er). Each iteration of your `IntFloatDict` is having to create new Python objects, which doesn't apply to your normal `dict` so it's easy to see why it could be faster

Comment: Just as an example: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/db59dd74df576345cc026cc0d6c99392d3649d3b/sklearn/cluster/_hierarchical_fast.pyx#L209

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the answer, it turned out that I have to use the IntFloatDict to operate in another pyx file. I'll try that.